# Can you please help 'tf.vectorize_map' Shape output error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to iterate over two arrays of both batch size 32 but with nested tf.vectorize_maps inside them so one for each Array, but they are different shapes so: (32,12-1,4) and (32,1024,4)
But I am doing this inside of model.fit/model.train_on_batch inside trainging_step inside nested tf.function. And I get this error.

And I get this error:

```
tf.vectorized Input to reshape is a tensor with 98304 values, but the requested shape has 288.
```

Attempts to fix or original.

```
IoUs = tf.vectorized_map(lambda batch: tf.vectorized_map(lambda ypredValues: 
tfytrue(ytrue[batch],ypredValues),ypred[batch]),tf.range(32)) 

IoUs = tf.vectorized_map(lambda batch: tf.vectorized_map(lambda ypredValues: tfytrue(batch[0],ypredValues),batch[1]),(ytrue,ypred))
```

It works when batch index is the same:

```
IoUs = tf.vectorized_map(lambda batch: tf.vectorized_map(lambda ypredValues: tfytrue(batch[1],ypredValues),batch[1]),(ytrue,ypred`))
```

But that is stupid because I can't parrel map the batch size and use the same array: maybe it's inside the other vectorized_maps but if anyone can help please, would be great. And the reason for me using tf.vectorized is that the speed increase is about 3000x over map_fn and I was able to use numpy as tf.py_func and tf.numpy_array returned invalid placeholder values.

But it does work with elems=(ytrue,ypred) but not in model.fit or model.train_on_batch.

```
RegLoss = tfIoU(batch[1],self.RPN(batch[0])[0])
```

Works Great but inside of train_on_batch/model.fit inside my custom train_step tfIoU(ytrue,ypred):

```
 Input to reshape is a tensor with 393216 values, but the requested shape has 4608
```

No reshaping is happening and it traces back to the batch vectorized map

**My question is that because it works the first time it like it sets the shape for the tf.vectorized map then it doesn't work the second time?**

**so (32,12,4) works then (32,8,4) fails then reverse the order and they do the same can anyone help?**

Answer (score 0):

It was the `tf.function()`; it can only be on the last nested function because it implies shapes no matter if its `expermital_relax_shapes=True`.